# How can I make my Dictionary add another item (Image), <string, string, image>?

Tags: c#, image, forms, xamarin

I am trying to store an image to my database (file) and I am not sure how I should execute it to send it as a image along with my strings, if i do a ToString(), it gives me an error because it only wants it as a source/image as my database is a "file".

```
static public async Task<bool> createData (string userId, string info1, string info2 , Image picture1 )
```

//so here above is the image i am trying to add along with my strings.

```
    {
        var httpClientRequest = new HttpClient ();

        httpClientRequest.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add ("X-Parse-Application-Id", appId);
        httpClientRequest.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add ("X-Parse-REST-API-Key", apiKey);

        var postData = new Dictionary <string, string> ();
```

// here above is the code and it is here that iam thinking the problem is, because the dictionary only accept strings, but when I try to write: 
var postData = new Dictionary < string, string, Image > it gives me an error.

```
        postData.Add ("userId", userId);
        postData.Add ("info1", info1);
        postData.Add ("info2", info2);
        postData.Add ("picture1", picture1); //error here because it is an image and it only wants strings.
```

So i was thinking that if it works i would add image to my dictionary and for my strings only type null on that 3rd command? or maybe there is a better option?

Comment: To store images in Parse, use a ParseFile.  https://parse.com/docs/dotnet/guide#files

Comment: Ah ok. Hmm, where should I convert it to parsefile? should I store my streamimage as string first?

Comment: This is advanced code for me. The picture is in stream form (Xamarin.Forms.StreamImageSource) but I am not sure where to go from here

Comment: Read the docs!  The second paragraph says that you can create a ParseFile from a stream.

Comment: ok, and do uknow what package i need to add to find ParseFile?

Comment: can't seem to find the streamcode, only the byte

Comment: darn it, cant seem to find the package or the "using .." because I cannot find the command ParseFile when i try to code.

Comment: You appear to be using the REST API, not the Xamarin component.  See https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide#quick-reference-files

Comment: ok getting closer but i get an error when i start the app "Self referencing loop detected for member with type system.reflection.monomethod.Path "picture1.stream.method.returnparameter"

Comment: I use a imagesource now, maybe i should use a image?

Comment: doesnt work with that either. do u have any clue?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [Tuple](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple(v=vs.110).aspx) class? You could use it like this:

```
Tuple<string, string, Image> postData =
     new Tuple<string, string, Image>(userId, info1, picture1);
```

Edit:

In response to your question below.  You can add the Tuples to a collection like so:

```
List<Tuple<string, string, Image>> postData = new List<Tuple<string, string, Image>>();
postData.Add(new Tuple<string, string, Image>(userId, info1, picture1));
```

Comment: okok nice. but how will i implement the database code, this for example: "info1", "userId" etc

Comment: I don't know.  That wasn't the question you asked.  None of your code shows any DB interaction.

Comment: Well i want to use it the same way as my directory, so i get the "databaseinfo" as well.

Comment: postData.Add ("userId", userId);
        postData.Add ("info1", info1);
        postData.Add ("info2", info2); this one. i cant "add" with a tuple

Comment: Oh, you can just create a List<Tuple<string, string, Image>>

Comment: hm okok, how would i implement my info in that? take my lists name and implement it the same way as my code above?

Comment: so like if i wanna structure the code the same way as i am now with the: postData.Add ("userId", userId);
        postData.Add ("info1", info1);
        postData.Add ("info2", info2);

how would it look?

Comment: If you want to keep your code the same you can just do a Dictionary<string, object>.  That way you can put objects of any type as the value.

Comment: oh ok, that worked. i get an error though: "Self referencing loop detected for member with type system.reflection.monomethod.Path "picture1.stream.method.returnparameter"

Comment: I use a imagesource now, maybe i should use a image?